# What does the last_modified_date of the user type mean in the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, api

The user API type contains a `last_modified_date` field, according to [the official documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user). However, I'm not sure what date it represents:

1. Does it refer to changes triggered by the system (e.g. reputation changes) or the user (e.g. about me edit)?
2. Does it only refer to system changes?
3. Does it only refer to user changes?
4. Does it include any changes in user profiles?

Comment: Cross-posted on Stack Apps: https://stackapps.com/q/9196/34061

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `last_modified_date` just pulls the `LastModifiedDate` column out of the Users table in the database. It doesn't run any kind of query to look for activity on the site to generate that date on the fly.

The things that do manually change that column when running:

- User edits any part of their public profile (about me, profile picture, website, etc) or has their profile copied from another site.
- User changes their verified email address on their account. *I'm not sure why, but this event appears to trigger an update on all profiles across the network regardless of which site the change is on, even if the change is within Teams. Updating at this event may also be removed in the near future as we continue reworking email settings to remove the old Users.Email column.*
- Moderator status is added or removed.

So essentially, the date is tied to editing your profile.